# Why does Spring Data Neo4j create an underscore prefixed label on nodes?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I realize that a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773454/spring-data-neo4j-create-duplicate-nodes-with-underscore), but I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind the approach of SDN to create a label matching my class name, and also creating the same label prefixed by an underscore.

So, for example, I have a Patient class.  When I create my @NodeEntity decorated Patient class through my Neo4j repository and then query it back through the Neo4j web console, I see Patient and _Patient as the labels.

As an extension to this question, say I have the following inheritance hierarchy of classes representing nodes:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Patient extends Person {
   //class definition here
}

@NodeEntity
public abstract class Person {
    //class definition here
}
```

When I save an instance of Patient to the database, it will have three labels: Person, Patient, _Patient.  Why wouldn't my node also have an _Patient label?

Comment: I may have answered my own question after re-reading the other question that I linked to, answer posted by @JohnMark13 -- "I cannot remember exactly but I think you will get a label for each class in your Java type hierarchy and one underscore prefixed label for the concrete java type of the Node."

I'd still be interested in understanding the strategy a bit better, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your hierarchy has more than 1 (not abstract) classes the label prefixed with _ allows SDN to determine the type properly.

E.g. when you similar hierarchy

```
Person
Patient extends Person
EbolaPatient extends Patient
```

then let's say you save instance of class Patient then the node will have _Patient label, when you save EbolaPatient instance it will have _EbolaPatient label.

If you then retrieve the nodes (e.g. as a collection using findAll on a person repository) SDN will correctly instantiate the entities as Patient and EbolaPatient.

Other option how to implement this would be to find a label that is most down the class hierarchy, which is a lot more complicated than having additional prefixed label.

To see details how this is implemented see [LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/typerepresentation/LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.java) class in SDN project.