# Neo4j + SDN Why node names starting _ appear

Tags: spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring Data for Neo4j for my app, i have introduced delete cypher query into app and see some wierd node names in Cypher query builder starting for _. For example i have node Vote and see that also _Vote exists in DB. Why they appear? something is done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Spring Data Neo4j create an underscore prefixed label on nodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728674/why-does-spring-data-neo4j-create-an-underscore-prefixed-label-on-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong, the ones with underscores denote the concrete type that was inserted in the database, for type-hierarchies.